# android css absolute positioned element goes out of the view when zoom

Tags: android, html, css, popup, css-position

I have popup. That popup has position relative and background overlay has position fixed. Something like that:

```
.popup{
  position:relative;
  top:100;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.popupBg {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
}

<div class="popupBg">
  <div class="popup">
  some html
  <input type="text">
  <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with android. When I click to input, it makes zoom. But half of the popup goes out of the view point. But if I "scroll" the view, the popup stays there and I can not move it left to see the rest of it. I can scroll only background. [Here](http://www.e-commercter.com/test/index5.html) is live example for better illustration.

I tried different positions and nothing helps. Any suggestions?

Comment: issue is only visible in andriod devices...?

Comment: I haven't tried other mobile devices yet, but I guess that also there.

Comment: I realized that I need to change .popupBg  position to absolute instead of fixed and it works. Then I will use jQuery(window).height() to set .popupBg height to the same height as page height.